# Convert a object column from an CSV to int in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I read data from a CSV file and almost all columns are of the object type. How can I convert them into int. I tried several options but without success. The CSV file is in image. I am especially interested in columns latitude and longitude.

[image: CSV File]

```
df = pd.read_csv('file'.csv)
de.head()

df.dtypes
listings       object
url            object
guests         object
bedrooms        int64
beds            int64
bathrooms       int64
room_type      object
price         float64
host_name      object
reviews         int64
stars         float64
location       object
latitude       object
longitude      object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Have you tried `df.longitude = df.longitude.astype(int)`?

Comment: How about: ```df['longitude'] = df['longitude'].astype(str).astype(int)```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can us `.astype()`, but perhaps need to do to `str` first then to `int`

```
df["yourColumn"] = df["yourColumn"].astype(str).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to change...

```
df['longitude'].to_numeric()
```